# Malformed version number string

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I recently installed a gem that was inappropriately named. My installation thinks the the version number is "Epub". The gem is called `Simple Epub Creator-0.0.0.gem`. I already know what I did wrong (used spaces) but now I need to fix it.

Whenever I run `gem` with any argument, including `uninstall`, I get this:

> C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/version.rb:200:in `initialize': Malformed version number string Epub (ArgumentError)gem

Followed by a stack trace as long as my arm. Is there an elegant fix to this problem, or is it better to just take the "sledgehammer" approach and nuke the installation, followed by a clean install of ruby and all of the gems I use?

Comment: Could you give example command lines for uninstalling the mis-named gem that have failed? Have you tried quoting the gem name on the command line e.g. `gem uninstall "Simple Epub Creator"`? Also, when you say "any argument", are you referring to manipulations of this one gem, or anything at all, including for example `gem list`

Comment: No matter what command I use, it will cause this error.

Comment: That's bad, it's a shame the gem packager/installer didn't warn you earlier. I don't know the answer to this one, although I would probably try identifying the gem folder where it has been installed and moving just that one folder to somewhere unrelated, seeing how that works before giving up and re-installing everything. If you have time to dig into the internals of `gem` to gain confidence in the correct answer, it would be a good learning experience, but might be quite a time sink.

Comment: I did find the method initialize in version.rb like Zoltan suggested, and commented out the first two lines. It doesn't argue anymore, but still, "gem uninstall" does nothing. I'm just going to nuke it. If a moderator is viewing this, please let me make sure this doesn't make things worse before this question gets closed.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when I inadvertently did a `rake:install` on a gem I was building that didn't yet have a version number assigned to it. Running `gem`, `bundle`, or `rake` with any commands resulted in the same error about a malformed version number.

What worked for me was manually deleting all instances of the offending gem in the `.rvm` folder. In my case, I had a gem named `dogecoin-` that was missing a version suffix. So `cd`ing into my `.rvm` directory and running `find . -path \*doge\* -delete` got me back into a functioning state.

Comment: I had the same issue after accidentally installing my own gem without giving it a version.  It showed up in my gemset as gems/portable_debugger-/ and specifications/portable_debugger-.gemspec.  Getting rid of them got me up and running again.

Answer (score 0):

My hunch is that `version.rb` goes through all the gems that you have installed, one of which is your misnamed epub creator.

Maybe you could take a look at the line 200 in the file `C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/version.rb`, see where it's trying to load the misnamed gem, find it and delete it?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem today.  I was using Ruby installed through [homebrew](/questions/tagged/homebrew).  I found remnants of the bad gem in the following folders.  Deleting the references from these two folders seems to have fixed the problem:

```bash
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/doc/
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/specifications/
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the files in the reference path, or some of the other suggested paths in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31801198/gem-malformed-version-number-string). Some thing that helped me was to first comment out the error be raised in the version.rb file on line 201. Then use the GEM PATH directory using `$ gem env` to find the path that had references to the gem. Make sure to remove everything from the doc, cache, and specifications folders. This finally solved my issue.