# Gem "Malformed Version Number String"

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm building a gem. I just got the basic project structure laid out, and I tried building it with `gem build my_gem.gemspec`, which worked fine. Then I installed it with `gem install My\ Gem-0.0.1.gem` and it still looked like it worked fine. Then I tried to run `irb` and I got this:

> /Users//.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/version.rb:206:in `initialize': Malformed version number string on (ArgumentError)

I tried making some changes and saved them. I ran `gem build my_gem.gemspec`. Same error.

All `irb`, `rails`, and `gem` sub-commands are generating a stack trace with this at the top. What did I do to break all of these commands and how do I reverse it?

Comment: Please show your gemspec file.

Comment: Will that help in undoing this error? I'm going to post a separate question about **why** the version string itself is failing, but this one is simply about uninstalling the gem to get commands working again.

Comment: Ah, separate question is even better here, you are right.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't really make that clear in the question.

Comment: downvote on the question because it's misleading - the OP only wanted "how do I reverse it" answers not " What did I do to break"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should manually delete your gem:

```
cd $GEM_HOME
find . -path \*my_gem\*
```

If everything looks good (i.e. there are no files which aren't related to your gem):

```
find . -path \*my_gem\* -delete
```

Before installing your gem again, make sure you specified `version` in your `.gemspec`.

**UPD**.

Other locations to look for the residue of the gem:

```
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-<version>@global
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-<version>
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/
# look for "GEM PATHS" section
gem env
# rbenv paths
~/.rbenv/versions
~/.gem/
```

**UPD2**

Problem solved! Steps taken:

This showed where exactly is this particular Rubygems executable, which failed to load:

```
rbenv which gem
# => /Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/gem
```

Then it turns out under `2.2.2` directory there were `cache`, `doc` and `specifications` directories, all of which contained a file or sub-directory with the residue of the broken gem. Deleting them all solved the problem.

Comment: Thank you ver much for the answer! I actually had tried to do this, but wasn't able to find my gem. Turns out it was because (as I had forgotten), the build used the name rather than the filename in creating the gem file (so the name wasn't `my_gem-0.0.1.gem`, but rather `My Gem-0.0.1.gem`). I deleted the directory in my gem path, and still the same error.

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: Woops! Mac OS 10.10.3! (Meant to put that in the above comment)

Comment: @RedBassett Basically, you need to get rid of gems in every location they possible are. I will update my answer.

Comment: Don't have `~/.rvm/`, and I checked `/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems`. Can't run `gem env` as it throws the error listed (as does any sub-command of `gem`).

Comment: Do you use rbenv? What is 'which gem' and 'echo $GEM_HOME' output?

Comment: `which gem` gives me `/Users/<username>/.rbenv/shims/gem` and `echo $GEM_HOME` is a blank line (emptystring?).

Comment: I added rbenv gem locations to my answer – check them (`cd ~/.gem`, `find . -path "My Gem"`) as well.

Comment: Still coming up with nothing at either (and no results for find). Is there any way that gems are cached in some manner?

Comment: Run `rbenv which gem` to know the real Rubygem executable which is called, post it back here. Must be some files which are left. There might be 'source_cache' file somewhere as well, you are right! Search for it in the directories listed above.

Comment: `/Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/gem`. Already checked the directories here for the gem. I'll dig into `2.2.2/` a bit more though.

Comment: Well, it gotta take your gem reference from somewhere. Run `grep "My Gem" -R .` (it could take some time to complete).

Comment: So inside the `2.2.2/` directory were directories `cache/`, `doc/`, and `specifications/`. All three had a file or sub-directory for my gem. Removing those solved it! Thanks a ton for helping me through all these steps. Please edit your above answer or submit a new one so I can mark it as accepted!

Answer (score 0):

(2016-May-24)
I solve this problem today.
I was try to learn how to write a gem.  and then cause this problem.
My guess is because my gem's name contain whitespace:  "hola 1c7"
and gem do not tell you how to solve this prbolem, this is annoying

you should go to: 

`/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/specifications`

delete that xxx.gemspec

in my case, my gem's name is "hola 1c7"
so I delete "hola 1c7-0.1.2.gemspec"
I think is the space cause problem.

if this not working,
try to search your gems name in `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/`
and delete all the file you can find,
in my case, first I delete

`hola 1c7.1.3.2.gem` from `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/cache`
so the command is :

`/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/cache$ sudo rm -rf hola\ 1c7-1.3.2.gem`

and then

`/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems$ sudo rm -rf hola\ 1c7-1.3.2/`

---

My Ruby Version   : Ruby 2.3.0
My Linux Version  : Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the files in the reference path, or some of the other suggested paths in this post. Some thing that helped me was to first comment out the error be raised in the version.rb file on line 201. Then use the GEM PATH directory using `$ gem env` to find the path that had references to the gem. Make sure to remove everything from the doc, cache, and specifications folders. This finally solved my issue.